# Snap to grid in edit mode

Tags: mesh, vertices

For some odd reason, each vertex thinks of it's own grid. 
[image]

I want to snap them along the grid line above them, but the result is this:

[image]
What's wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activate the *Absolute Grid Alignment* option

[image]

**EDIT** In your case it seems to not working because of the armature, Blender can't figure out how to snap the vertex the final transformation of the vertex to the grid because of the deformation introduced by the rig.

Comment: Still didn't work. [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/AiN3DKJ.png)

Comment: Not sure what the problem could be. Can you [share a **simplified** blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I'll edit my post. It may look strait at the moment, for I'm going and manualy straitening them out.

Comment: Ok, figured it out, your rig is causing deformations, and Blender can't snap to grid that way. Answer updated above.